# Regular expression not extracting the exact pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am working in Java to read a string of over 100000 characters. 
I have a list of keywords, that I search the string for, and if the string is present I call a function which does some internal processing.

The kind of keyword I have is "face", for example - I wish to get all the patterns where I have matches for "faces" not "facebook". I can accept a space character behind the face in the string so if in a string I have a match like " face" or " faces" or "face " or " faces" i can accept that too. However I can not accept "duckface" or "duckface " etc.

I have written the regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+"+keyword+"s\\s+|\\s+");
```

where keyword is my list of keywords, but I am not getting the desired results. Can you read my description and please suggest what might be issue and how I can fix it?

Also if a pointer to a really good regex for Java page is shared I would appreciate that as well.

Thank you Contributers ..

Edit

The reason I know it is not working is I have used the following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+"+keyword+"s\\s+|\\s+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(myInputDataSting);
            if(m.find())
            {
                System.out.println("Its a Match: "+m.group());
}
```

This returns a blank string...

Comment: How is it not working? What Strings is it missing?

Comment: You need to parenthesize alternative options, but it's even better in your case to do `+"s?\\s+"` to make the `s` optional. Also, make sure to `+Pattern.quote(keyword)+` your keywords, otherwise they may mess up your Pattern.

Comment: I often use [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) site as a tutorial/reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `keyword` is `"face"`, then your current regex is

```
\s+faces\s+|\s+
```

which matches *either* one or more whitespace characters, followed by `faces`, followed by one or more whitespace characters, *or* one or more whitespace characters. (The pipe `|` has very low precedence.)

What you really want is

```
\bfaces?\b
```

which matches a word boundary, followed by `face`, optionally followed by `s`, followed by a word boundary.

So, you can write:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+keyword+"s?\\b");
```

(though obviously this will only work for words like `face` that form their plurals by simply adding `s`).

You can find a comprehensive listing of Java's regular-expression support at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, but it's not much of a tutorial. For that, I'd recommend just Googling "regular expression tutorial", and finding one that suits you. (It doesn't have to be Java-specific: most of the tutorials you'll find are for flavors of regular-expression that are *very* similar to Java's.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\b"+keyword+"s?\b");

, where keyword is not plural. \\b means that keyword must be as a complete word in searched string. s? means that keyword's value may end with s.

If you are not familar enough with regular expressions I recommend reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html, because there are examples and explanations.