# Regular expression in java not resulting desired results

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to extract keywords from a text string having lots of random data.  as shared at [Regular expression not extracting the exact pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342985/regular-expression-not-extracting-the-exact-pattern/9344218#9344218), i created a regex :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+myKeywordToSearch+"s?\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

However this was ignoring any keywords with number/special character just before the keyword starts.

As mentioned i need to have all those keywords count which are like :

```
12312312face
1face
$face
234%#$face
faces
4faces
$faces
 faces
 face's
 faces'
```

Though i can not accept keywords like:

```
facebook
duckface
```

I have written the regex

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\W"+myKeywordToSearch+"s?\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

where keyword is my list of keywords, but I am not getting the desired results. The count of keywords is very low and is not as much as i expected. Can you read my description and please suggest what might be issue and how I can fix it?

My Regex requirement is to search a keyword in the file which can be :

```
5face 
7face
$face
%face
 face
faces
face's
faces'
face'
face4
face$
face    <--Space after face
```

but it shall not read

```
duckface
duckface1
duckface$
facebook
 facebook
3facebook
&facebook 
and so on...
```

My Regex attempts have not been working great so far..

Can anyone please suggest something. Thank you.

My multiple attempts have been

```
("\\b"+mySearchKeyWord+"s?\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            ("\\b\\W"+mySearchKeyWord+"s?\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            ("[0-9]{}//w[a-bA-B]+ or [0-9]{}//w["+mySearchKeyWord+"]++",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            ("[^a-z\\s]*"+mySearchKeyWord+"?[^\\s]*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            ("[^\\s]*"+mySearchKeyWord+"?[^\\s]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            ("[^\\s]*"+mySearchKeyWord+"s?\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            ("[^\\s]*\\W*"+mySearchKeyWord+"s?\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Have you tried writing unit tests as a starting point so you can start with some knowns that aren't truly random?

Comment: face's needs to taken out of what you say you need to match, I believe, surely you don't wish to match that. (would make no sense, it isn't a word)

Answer (score 1):

\b is a word boundary, and numbers are included in what can form a word, so "1face" is considered a word in regular expressions, meaning that \bface\b will not match it. I'm not sure which special characters are considered part of words in Java, so this might also be the problem with words starting with them.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern looks OK, so to understand what is wrong you have to discover your input and find specific words that are not caught by your pattern.

But may I recommend you something? If your texts are relatively short and number of keywords is relatively small you should create one pattern that contains all keywords separated by `|` and then run your pattern only once.

As far as I understand now you are running your pattern N times over whole text where N is number of your keywords. It is very ineffective.

But if you have a lot of keywords (thousands or so) you should split your text to separate words and use data structure like `Map` to locate the keywords. Too long patterns do not work well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim to be a regular expression expert, but this seems to catch all the words in your example:

```
[^a-z\s]*faces?[^\s]*
```

This basically finds "face" or "faces" and everything before it and after it up to the point it finds a space.  Wrapping this entire expression in parenthesis will put all the words in a capture group.

Comment: I guess the ^a-z can be removed.  `[^\s]*faces?[^\s]*` should work.

Comment: I don't think he wants to match words like 'facebook' and 'buttface', which this one does.

Comment: @sweaver2112 exactly... i refined it to "[^\\s]*"+keyword+"s?\\b"

Answer (score 0):

You can use look-ahead and look-behind instead of word boundaries:

```
"(^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z]))(faces?)($|(?=[^a-zA-Z]))"
```

this asserts that I must be able to see non-letter characters (or start/end of string) immediately preceding and after "face/faces".

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense: why are you searching for a boundary, then a nonword char, then an arbitrary string? It looks like you don’t understand what boundaries do.

A `\b` boundary is precisely equivalent to:

```
(?:(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w))
```

See your problem? When you write `\b\Wface` you require a wordchar, then a nonwordchar, then `face`.

Don’t use boundaries if you do not understand them.

Comment: So what can be the search pattern i should use ?

Comment: @typedef1 Get rid of the `\W`.  Just use `\bTERMs?\b`, but you must verify that the first char at the beginning and the last char at the end of your `TERM` are indeed word characters, or else the `\b` will work against you. What happened when you prototyped this with command-line tools like `grep` or `perl`?  Please tell me you’re not trying to develop orginal regexes in pure Java from scratch! You always want to debug them using purpose-built utilities, like those I just mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

So keywords are just character successions and so it appears that you might not want to use  a pattern matcher but instead try java.regex.pattern.

For the regex inject something like:

```
 [0-9]{*}//w[a-bA-B]+ or [0-9]{*}//w[face]++
```

Here is a a tester [RegExp](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm).